# How to pass variables in functions back to main in Powershell?

Tags: function, powershell, parameters, return-value, powershell-3.0

I'm taking variable objects from a Windows Form and making them their own variables to be easier to work with.

```
$btnSubmit.Add_Click({ Submit })

function Submit(){ 
    $FirstName =  $txtFirstName.Text 
    $MiddleInit = $txtMiddleInitial.Text 
    $LastName = $txtLastName.Text 
    $JobTitle = $cboJobTitle.Text 
    $CSC = $cboCSC.Text 
}
```

How would I go about passing these values to the main so I can reference them later in the script as well as in other functions?

Comment: Change the scope on the variables to `$script:` or `$global:` depending on how your script structure is set up.  As an improvement: you can pass the function directly to the event: `Add_Click($Function:Submit)`

Answer (score 3):

You can scope the variables Globally then they would be available everywhere:

$btnSubmit.Add_Click({ Submit })

```
function Submit(){ 
    $GLOBAL:FirstName =  $txtFirstName.Text 
    $GLOBAL:MiddleInit = $txtMiddleInitial.Text 
    $GLOBAL:LastName = $txtLastName.Text 
    $GLOBAL:JobTitle = $cboJobTitle.Text 
    $GLOBAL:CSC = $cboCSC.Text 
}
```

Comment: Or if you don't want them globally scoped (which some people don't) you can scope them at the script level instead `$SCRIPT:`

Comment: Just to note, if you're importing the script to be used in another script (dot-sourcing or `Import-Module`), `$script:` will not be accessible.

Comment: That is why I use $GLOBAL: as a general rule but sometimes people pitch a fit over that.

Comment: I'm one of those people because of scope pollution, but global scope has its uses when it comes to working with UI-interactions like this one.  I point that out because they pointed out they're working with multiple scripts